# How to change initial culture on Luis app?

Tags: nlp, chatbot, azure-language-understanding, culture

I created an en-us application in LUIS, but I want to work with this same application, changing the culture to Portuguese. Is there any option to change and be able to import a .json with culture in pt-bR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, once the culture is fixed, you cannot change it. Upgrading the version does not work either. The only way for you to work on it is to delete the application and then create a new one

Answer (score 1):

you can download the app as JSON. and change the fields,  "culture": "pt-bR",
  "tokenizerVersion": "1.0.0". then upload the json as a new project in luis app. ( tokenizerVersion might change so please check on that)